# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro en cascada o en jerarquía en flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, vscode

muy buenos días.

Hace unos días había formulado esta pregunta pero creo que no había sido claro o como me comentaron era muy amplia la cuestión, vuelvo a generar esta pregunta especificando un poco mas el caso que presento.

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Flutter bajo Visual Stude Code, en esta aplicación tengo un slider de imágenes que al presionar cada cuadro te manda a otra ventana, esto funciona muy bien, lo que me entro como duda es si se puede en vez de mandar a otra ventana te mande o agregue como filtro cada cuadro, ejemplo en el primer slider tengo tres imágenes una de carros, otra de aviones y otra de barcos, que al presionar sobre alguna opción despliegue en la parte de abajo los años por ejemplo y de los años desplace otro slider de marcas ejemplo asta llegar a un punto que ya no pueda tener mas opciones, ósea de lo general a lo particular

[image: Anexo de imagen]

El código que me sirve pero para abrir la información en otra ventana es el siguiente:

```
 itemBuilder: ( _ , int index){
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'details', arguments: 'movie-instance'),//Accion para enviar a otra ventana 
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          child: FadeInImage(
            placeholder: AssetImage('assets/no-image.jpg'), 
            image: AssetImage('assets/no-image.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Lo que busco es que dentro de la ventana vaya realizando ese filtro asta llegar a lo ultimo de filtros y en el ultimo slider del filtro mandar a otra pantalla para mandar el resultado de una consulta o filtro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He realizado un pequeño ejemplo de lo que podría ser una aproximación de lo que pides.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const type = <String>['Car'];
const brands = <String>['Fiat', 'Mercedes'];
const years = <String>['2020', '2018', '2016'];

class MultiSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const MultiSlider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MultiSlider'),
      ),
      body: const MultiList(),
    );
  }
}

class MultiList extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MultiListState createState() => _MultiListState();
}

class _MultiListState extends State<MultiList> {
  bool showBrands = false;
  bool showYears = false;

  final brandList = <String>[];
  final yearList = <String>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const spacer = SizedBox(height: 24);

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          OptionList(
            options: type,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                showBrands = !showBrands;
                if (!showBrands && showYears) showYears = false;
                brandList
                  ..clear()
                  ..addAll(brands);
              });
            },
          ),
          if (showBrands) ...[
            spacer,
            OptionList(
              options: brandList,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  showYears = !showYears;
                  yearList
                    ..clear()
                    ..addAll(years);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
          if (showYears) ...[
            spacer,
            OptionList(
              options: yearList,
              onTap: () {
                // do something
              },
            ),
          ],
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OptionList extends StatelessWidget {
  const OptionList({
    Key? key,
    required this.options,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> options;
  final GestureTapCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const divider = Divider();

    return ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: options.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
        title: Text(options[index]),
        onTap: onTap,
      ),
      separatorBuilder: (_, __) => divider,
    );
  }
}
```

Si observas, dentro del widget Column, puedes usar condicionales if para mostar u ocultar un widget o lista de widgets.

El uso de las listas internas del widget: `brandList` y `yearList` en este ejemplo es redundante, pero podrías usarlo para que según que opción escoja el usuario, se me muestre un filtro u otro.